# Do Apple TVs work only with Apple routers?

Tags: wifi, appletv

Can one in principle get Apple TV to join/extend a wireless network even if that wireless network is from a non-Apple wifi router?

Edit:

By that I mean: Can one control an Apple TV from a Macbook if the network that the Macbook has joined is not broadcast by an Apple router?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Apple TV is a client device, meaning it connects to the router. However, the current generation Apple TV does not have the capability to extend the network; i.e. act as a router.

Edit: To answer the question you edited in, yes, you can control the Apple TV from any Wi-fi network, as long as it is a 802.11a,b,g, or n network. Wi-fi is Wi-fi, no matter what device is broadcasting it.

Answer (score 2):

Join: yes. Any 802.11 a/b/g/n network should work. Extend: no. The Apple TV can't extend any wireless network.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can control an Apple TV from a Macbook even if the network that the Macbook has joined is not broadcast by an Apple router, but as others pointed out it cannot act as a router by itself.